# Opening large Images using BitmapImage.SetSource - Insufficient Memory Exception

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am creating a Silverlight 4 application that needs to display thumbnails of images before uploading them to the server. The code I have works perfectly for images under 15mb but when I try and open large images (some over 30mb) I get the following Exception:

> ```
> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
> ```

The error is pretty self explanatory however my question is....is there an alternative way of opening large images or increasing the memory available to the Silverlight application?

I am testing this on a machine with 8gb of RAM and when I check the IE process hosting the application memory usage peaks at around 250mb before throwing the exception so its fairly safe to assume my machine is not running out of memory.

The code I am using to open the full image is as follows although I have omitted the code for generating the resized thumbnails as it currently never gets that far with large images:

```
private BitmapImage OpenImage(Stream stream)
{
     byte[] fullRead = this.ReadFully(stream);
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fullRead);

     BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
     bi.SetSource(ms);

     return bi;
}

private byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[input.Length];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You basically either run out of memory (remember Silverlight is sandboxed) and/or resources (i.e. Handles or similar).

Check [this](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/12/17/silverlight-s-big-image-problem-and-what-you-can-do-about-it.aspx) out for a solution to the problem you describe including source code etc.

Comment: @Yehia - Thanks for the link but my code to resize the thumbnails is actually based on that very post. However my problem is I can't open the original image in order to resize it.

Comment: @MarkB29 If you can't even open the original image then I suspect that silverlight isn't setup to use all available memory... nothing you can solve from your code AFAIK since that is security sensitive... there are also differences between in-browser and out-of-browser Silverlight apps...